# JSON Conditional formatting for Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, column-formatting

I'm a bit of a noob about JSON and I want to use it to my benefit. What I want to do based on the attachment is the following:

[image: Sharepoint example]

Latin Qual Required? column is set to Choice setting and Latin Qual Date column is set to Short Date setting

- If Latin Qual Required? column has "Yes" and the Latin Qual Date is empty, change cell to background color with a specific hex code or the "error" class with Icon.
- If Latin Qual Required? column has "Yes" and the Latin Qual Date is entered, change cell to background color with a specific hex code  "success" class with Icon.
- If Latin Qual Required? column has "Yes" and the Latin Qual Date is empty, change cell to red or the "error" class with Icon.
- If Latin Qual Required? column has "No" a change cell to background color with a specific hex code

Comment: Which columns cell background you want to change? or you want to change the background color of whole row?

Answer (score 0):

The below JSON helps you to get the required output. Add the below snippet to the in  **Latin Qual Required?** field column format.
I assumed the internal name for **Latin Qual Required?** is **Title**
and internal name for **Latin Qual date** is **StartDate**

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "attributes": {
"class": "=if(Number([$StartDate]) == 0, 'sp-field-severity--blocked', if(@currentField == 'Yes','sp-field-severity--good','sp-field-severity--blocked')) + ' ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary'"

  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "display": "inline-block",
        "padding": "0 4px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "=if(Number([$StartDate]) == 0, 'Warning', if(@currentField == 'Yes','CheckMark','Warning'))"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "@currentField"
    }
  ]
}
```

The output looks likes below,

[image]g

I hope this helps to solve your query.

Comment: hi, i'm so sorry for the delay.  is it possible to just use background colors via Hex vs the classes to have more options?

Comment: @SLang yes! You can add a `"background-color": "#F3F3F3"` to the `style` properties. You can use the same expression from the `class` attribute and just replace the values with hex colors.